# How to make changes to a JSON file and save them?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have one JSON file and I want to assign the key (food_image) value in it to index value in a loop.. for example `food_image0, food_image1 ... food_image{loop index}`.

Then I want to save this JSON file as JSON file. All values ​​with a `food_image` key will be prefixed with `"food_image"` and will be rewritten by adding the index suffix in the loop. It's all I want:

JSON

```json
{
    "DATABASE":
    [
        {
            "food_id": 0,
            "food_name": "Food Name ABC",
            "food_image": "imagesite/abc.jpg", // food_image_0
            "food_kcal": "32",
            "units":
            [
                {
                    "amount": "15.0000",
                    "calory": "32.4877372383",
                },
                {
                    "amount": "110.0000",
                    "calory": "238.243406414",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "food_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Food Name XYZ",
            "food_image": "imagesite/xyz.jpg", // food_image_1
            "food_kcal": "32",
            "units":
            [
                {
                    "amount": "15.0000",
                    "calory": "32.4877372383",
                },
                {
                    "amount": "110.0000",
                    "calory": "238.243406414",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Python:

```py
import json
with open('json_file.json',encoding="utf8") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

obj = json.loads(data)
for idx, i in enumerate(obj['DATABASE']):
    print(i["food_image"])
```

Resulting JSON:

```json
{
    "DATABASE":
    [
        {
            "food_id": 0,
            "food_name": "Food Name ABC",
            "food_image": "food_image_0.jpg",
            "food_kcal": "32",
            "units":
            [
                {
                    "amount": "15.0000",
                    "calory": "32.4877372383",
                },
                {
                    "amount": "110.0000",
                    "calory": "238.243406414",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "food_id": 1,
            "food_name": "Food Name XYZ",
            "food_image": "food_image_1.jpg"
            "food_kcal": "32",
            "units":
            [
                {
                    "amount": "15.0000",
                    "calory": "32.4877372383",
                },
                {
                    "amount": "110.0000",
                    "calory": "238.243406414",
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly how you want the JSON file to look after making changes? Also which part are you stuck on, generating the right content or writing the changes back to your file?

Comment: I actually explained it as a comment line. I did it, please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you read your JSON file into a Python object, mutate the object, then write it back to a file.

In the example below, I create a separate file instead of overwriting the original (which I would recommend you do too in case of bugs should you do other mutations).

```
import json
import os

source = 'json_file.json'
dest = 'updated.json'

with open(source) as f:
    content = json.load(f)

for i, entry in enumerate(content['DATABASE']):
    _, extension = os.path.splitext(entry['food_image'])
    entry['food_image'] = f'food_image_{i}{extension}'

with open(dest, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(content, f)
```

Comment: This answer is completely correct. thank you for everything. I hope it can help other people too